# joomla sh404sef - unable to pass dynamic session value into url, it is always set with one value

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have used sh404sef component in my joomla project. Where it is working fine. But am in situation to pass city name onto url. I have saved city name into session according to user selection.

I wrote in router.php to pass city as,

```
$slt_city = JRequest::getVar("slt_city");
    if(empty($slt_city)){
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $slt_city = $session->get( 'slt_city' );
    }

if (!empty($slt_city)) {
        $segments[] = strtolower($slt_city);
        unset($query['city']);
    }
```

But it is always shows in url with only one city. There is no any duplication too. Can anyone give solution to pass session value to URL ?

i need to change url from xxxxx.com/electronics/wholesalers to xxxxx.com/bangalore/electronics/wholesalers 
xxxxx.com/mysore/electronics/wholesalers